# How to create array of alternating colour patterns (blue and white) with the first and last being a third colour (red)

Tags: node-editor

I am trying to replicate a swimming pool lane divider (see picture). I have created a sequence of the two main colours (blue and white) using a checker texture node but I don't know how to make it so that the first portion and last portion of the divider is coloured in red.[[image: current nodesreference for lane divider colour sequence]

Comment: What is first and last portion of the divider?

Comment: Hi Martynas, thanks for your answer! The first and last portion of the divider are red, so the sequence is: RED- WHITE-BLUE-WHITE-BLUE-(...)WHITE-BLUE-RED.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Color Ramp node to define the colors and Math node in Modulo mode to repeat the pattern:

[image]

Note that Generated texture coordinates depend on world distances so the numbers depend on your object size and will be different for your situation.

Also, this is only one way to do this, there are probably hundreds of other ways that are just as good.